# How can i run complete suite of performance scripts (Jmeter) in jenkins

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jenkins-pipeline

I have my jenkin job and performace scripts placed in git hub , i have created jenkins file using groovy in my repository where i have done all the configuration. Right now i have to mention each and every script in jenkins file which i want to run.

Is there any way or standard to write the jenkins files in such a way it will pull all scripts from folder and i just have to mention folder name instead of each and every jmx scripts in jenkins file.

We have different folder (1,2,3) having more than 150 scripts each and my requirement is to run folder wise and to mention folder name in jenkins file instead of giving each and every script name.

Please let me know how can i do this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [findFiles() snippet](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#findfiles-find-files-in-the-workspace), something like:

```
def jmeterScripts = findFiles(glob: '*.jmx')

//and then:

files.each { file -> jmeter -n -t file.getAbsolutePath() .....}
```

Also it might be easier to reconsider the overall approach, if you switch to [JMeter Maven plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin) it will automatically pick up scripts from `src/test/jmeter` folder, for more flexible selection you can use [regular expressions](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Selecting-Tests-To-Run#specifying-testfilesincluded-using-regex)